# Full Screen Map Beneath NavBar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I'm trying to add a map as a full screen background below my Bootstrap NavBar, but at the moment my code is causing the bottom of the map to overflow the page.

I've tried different margins and positions and I cant get it to show the map within the bounds of the page under the navbar. I understand part of the issue is having top:50px but I don't know how to rectify the problem.

My CSS code is as follows:

```
  #map { 
  /* Set rules to fill background */
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;

     /* Set up positioning */
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;

   }
```

Here is a screen shot of my page, you can see in the bottom right that the map attribution and controls have been cut off: [image: MapDispla]

Comment: Can you replicate this in jsFiddle or Bootply? Without knowing what your surrounding code looks like, it's hard to help.

Comment: You say you know the issue is top:50px; is there a reason you need it to be there?

Comment: use  `position:absolute;border-top:50px solid #fff;top:0px;`  instead of `position:fixed;top:50px;` for `#map` http://jsfiddle.net/7291hLkx/2/

Comment: @DavidG see Dr.Molle's jsfiddle, his method has solved the issue and the code was similar to my own. Thanks :)

Comment: @skv it was set as 50px because that is the height of my navbar and I wanted the map to start below that with no gap

Comment: @Dr.Molle that has worked thanks very much for the help!

Comment: @Dr.Molle thats an answer :) I guess you can post it so it benefits future visitors?

Answer (score 0):

You're setting your map height as 100%. Try setting a fixed height, instead.

If it's too wide, add this to your CSS files.

```
.gmnoprint img {
    max-width: none; 
}
```

Alternatively, try this if that doesn't work:

```
html,body {
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%;
}
.whateveryourmapis {
    height: auto; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

Comment: The reason for height: 100% was to ensure that the map kept it's size relative to the window. 

If I set a fix height, then I'd maybe encounter problems displaying the map when resizing. Thanks for the help though, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need wait until div in which is content is displayed because google map chcecks it width wery early - and gets small width (or 0) and dont render.

Try this:

```
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    });
```

It is callback - when div for content after click on tab is dispayed THEN 'resize' google map on correct width.

For me this works.